# What are possible story types in Asana API?

Tags: asana, asana-api

This information is missing from the story endpoint documentation here: https://asana.com/developers/api-reference/stories

Do you know what are the possible values for type field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are currently only two types: `system` and `comment` - comments being text entered by a user, and `system` being all the other stories, such as tasks being completed, moved, re-assigned, etc.